# About merging lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm studying prolog right now, but I met some interesting questions.

The goal is to print out a list of a family relations,

the facts are:

```
parent(john, paul).
parent(john, mary).
parent(paul, henry).
parent(paul, june).
parent(henry, helen).
parent(mary, adam).
```

The goal is to print the list as follow,

```
L =
[john,
  [paul,
    [henry,
      [helen]
    ],
    [june]
  ],
  [mary,
    [adam]
  ]
]
```

Here is my code and what I get now,

```
descendantTree(X, [X|[T1]]) :- parent(X, Tmp),                        
                            descendantTree(Tmp, T1).
descendantTree(X, [X]) :- not(parent(X, Tmp)).

[debug]  ?- descendantTree(john, L).
         L = [john, [paul, [henry, [helen]]]] ;
         L = [john, [paul, [june]]] ;
         L = [john, [mary, [adam]]] ;
         false.
```

I'm lost at combining those results, if I can get any help, it will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use `findall/3`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your help, I've tried findall/3, but it just combine the three lists into a list, but it is still different than what the goal is. Or you mean using findall/3 inside the descendantTree() ?

Comment: you make a function that for a given element prepends that element together with a list of all descendants (these descendants can be generated with a recursive call to the *same* predicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track here, it is clear that the first element of the list for a `descendantTree/2` of `X` is `X` itself, and this can be followed (optionally) by a list of children.

We can generate these child lists with a `findall/3` call, where we make a recursive call to our own predicate, like:

```
descendantTree(X, [X | Ds]) :-
    findall(D, (parent(X, C), descendantTree(C, D)), Ds).
```

Given there are no "childs" `C`, then `Ds` will be empty, so we will generate a singleton list with the childless parent as element.

In case there are children, then we will generate the descendants `D` for that child, and each of these descendants will be added to the tail of the list `Ds`. By doing this recursively, this thus will generate the family tree from the given person up to all descendants.

For example:

```
?- descendantTree(john, L).
L = [john, [paul, [henry, [helen]], [june]], [mary, [adam]]].
```

an unfortunate part is however that we can not easily generate the tree in reverse:

```
?- descendantTree(P, L).
L = [P, [paul, [henry, [helen]], [june]], [mary, [adam]], [henry, [helen]], [june], [helen], [adam]].
```

here the free variable `P` will simply match anything, and thus will match all `parent/2` facts. We can prevent this. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will figure that out later when I am back home!